# issue parsing json file with Langchain

Tags: node.js, langchain

Need some help.

I have the following json content in a file and would like to use langchain.js and gpt to parse , store and answer question such as

for example:

"find me jobs with 2 year experience" ==> should return a list

"I have knowledge in javascript find me jobs" ==> should return the jobs pbject

I use langchain json loader and I see the file is parse but it say that it find 13 docs . There is only be 3 docs in file . Is the json structure not correct?

Here is snippet of my parse code

```
const loader = new DirectoryLoader(docPath, {
  ".json": (path) => new JSONLoader(path),
});

const docs = await loader.load();
console.log(docs);
console.log(docs.length);
```

Here is my input data

```
[
  {
    "jobid":"job1",
    "title":"software engineer"
    "skills":"java,javascript",
    "description":"this job requires a associate degrees in CS and 2 years experience"
  },
   {
    "jobid":"job2",
    "skills":"math, accounting, spreadsheet",
    "description":"this job requires a degrees in accounting and 2 years experience"
  },
   {
    "jobid":"job3",
    "title":"programmer"
    "skills":"java,javascript,cloud computing",
    "description":"this job requires a ,master degrees in CS and 3 years experience"
  }
  
]

OUTPUT
[
  Document {
    pageContent: 'job1',
    metadata: {
      source: 'langchain-document-loaders-in-node-js/documents/jobs.json',
      line: 1
    }
  },
  Document {
    pageContent: 'software engineer',
    metadata: {
      source: 'langchain-document-loaders-in-node-js/documents/jobs.json',
      line: 2
    }
  },
  Document {
    pageContent: 'java,javascript',
    metadata: {
      source: 'langchain-document-loaders-in-node-js/documents/jobs.json',
      line: 3
    }
  },
  Document {
    pageContent: 'this job requires a associate degrees in CS and 2 years experience',
    metadata: {
      source: 'langchain-document-loaders-in-node-js/documents/jobs.json',
      line: 4
    }
  },
  Document {
    pageContent: 'job2',
    metadata: {
      source: 'langchain-document-loaders-in-node-js/documents/jobs.json',
      line: 5
    }
  },
```

...

Comment: Thank you. Please add your answer so I can give you credit

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Comment: Sorry. I did not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON contains a Javascript array of three Javascript objects. Two of them have four properties, and one has three. All the properties have text strings for values. It looks like your parser pulls each property into one of its Documents.

You need to find a way to tell your parser that each Javascript object is one of its Documents.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue here despite adding a pointer. I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchainjs/issues/3071), which was opened recently.

An alternative work-around would be to turn JSON into CSV.